# replace div with new div with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, fadeout, fadein

I need some help with something simple! It's a jquery function to change div content.

The basic idea is to have a container div with a div (div1) inside it that contains 4 images. I want the function to change the div content (with a fade) inside the container div from div1 to div 2.

Div 1 and 2 are identical ; it's just the images that are being replaced.

Here is the html:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>xx</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
        <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <head>
    <body>
        <input id="doit" type="button" value="clickme">
        <div id="containerdiv">
            <div id="div1">
                <img class="SW">    
                <img src="Img/SW_A.jpg" height=125px width 125px >
                <img src="Img/SW_B.jpg" height=125px width 125px >
                <img src="Img/SW_C.jpg" height=125px width 125px >
                <img src="Img/SW_D.jpg" height=125px width 125px >
            </div> 
        </div>
        <div id="div2">
            <img class="SW" >  
            <img src="Img/SW_E.jpg" height=125px width 125px >
            <img src="Img/SW_F.jpg" height=125px width 125px >
            <img src="Img/SW_G.jpg" height=125px width 125px >
            <img src="Img/SW_H.jpg" height=125px width 125px >
        </div> 
    <body>
<html>
```

And the script:

```
$('#doit').click(function(){
    $('#div1').fadeOut('slow', function() {
        $('#div1').html$('#div2')
        $('#div1').fadeIn('slow');
    });    
});
```

The function does work when I put simple text as the content for div2:

```
$('#doit').click(function(){
    $('#div1').fadeOut('slow', function() {
        $('#div1').html('my new content')
         $('#div1').fadeIn('slow');
    });    
});
```

But I want the div to be replaced by a new similar div, not by text! I've searched a lot on jquery for this simple code, but can't seem to find what I'm looking for.

Also, I need to find a way to hide the content of div2 from the page before loading from the function.

Any help would be really great.

Comment: Would you need to keep the content of div1 in the DOM to return to it later?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are trying to implement a carousel. To change images. 
You could use http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#carousel its pretty handy and easy to use and customize.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your code is not working is because your syntax is a little off and you aren't quite using the `.html()` method correctly. I've also used your button to hide the container, then make it reappear with the new content in it. See my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fmpeyton/kFQ4q/).

**HTML**

```
<input id="doit" type="button" value="clickme">
<div id="containerdiv">


<div id="div1">

<img class="SW">    
<img src="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSJ6LGVbd2hRo9GEemMi-EWK6e8uhifbtdanY1KotPsSr_Sut0pVw" height=125px width 125px >
<img src="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSJ6LGVbd2hRo9GEemMi-EWK6e8uhifbtdanY1KotPsSr_Sut0pVw" height=125px width 125px >
<img src="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSJ6LGVbd2hRo9GEemMi-EWK6e8uhifbtdanY1KotPsSr_Sut0pVw" height=125px width 125px >
<img src="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSJ6LGVbd2hRo9GEemMi-EWK6e8uhifbtdanY1KotPsSr_Sut0pVw" height=125px width 125px >

</div> 

</div>

<div id="div2">

<img class="SW" >  
<img src="http://factoryjoe.com/projects/wordpress-icon/files/wordpress-icon-128.png" height=125px width 125px >
<img src="http://factoryjoe.com/projects/wordpress-icon/files/wordpress-icon-128.png" height=125px width 125px >
<img src="http://factoryjoe.com/projects/wordpress-icon/files/wordpress-icon-128.png" height=125px width 125px >
<img src="http://factoryjoe.com/projects/wordpress-icon/files/wordpress-icon-128.png" height=125px width 125px >

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#div1{ }
#div2{ display: none; }
```

**jQuery**

```
    $(function(){
    $('#doit').click(function(){
        $('#containerdiv').fadeOut('slow', function() {
            $('#containerdiv').html($('#div2').html());
            $('#containerdiv').fadeIn('slow');
        });
    })
});
```

Of course, this is if you just want to switch from `div1` to `div2`. If you want further functionality, you would need to expand the code further.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `.replaceWith()` like so. But then again as the other poster below states, you may be trying to implement a carousel feature. If this is true, then I'd say don't bother reinventing the wheel!

Simple version of what you are trying to do:

HTML:

```
<input id="doit" type="button" value="clickme">
<div id="div1"> 
    <img src="http://placehold.it/125x125"/>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/125x125"/>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/125x125"/>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/125x125"/>

</div> 

<div id="div2" class="hidden">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/125x125"/>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/125x125"/>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/125x125"/>

    </div>
```

Javascript:

```
$('#doit').click(function(){
    $('#div1').fadeOut('slow', function() {
    $('#div1').replaceWith($('#div2'));
     $('#div2').removeClass('hidden');
    $('#div1').fadeIn('slow');
});    
})
```

Sample CSS:

```
.hidden {
    display:none;
    background-color:red;
}
```

First div has 4 images, second div on click has 3 images (to set them apart as I didnt have any good sample images to use)

http://jsfiddle.net/m9qAY/1/

Comment: Adaam, that that is exactly what I was looking for, and it worked. Now I have created a button to go back to div1 (let's call it 'doitback') with the same fade effect. Only, when I add the button and switch the divs, I can't get the div1 content to reappear again. If you've got a suggestion for this, that'd be perfect.

Answer (score 0):

I'd put them both in the container, rather than moving them in and out. Then just show one at a time. Building on Fillip Peyton's fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/kFQ4q/1/

```
$(function () {
    var vis = 1;
    $('#doit').click(function () {
        $('#containerdiv').fadeOut('slow', function () {
            $('#div'+vis).hide();
            vis = vis === 1 ? 2 : 1;
            $('#div'+vis).show();
            $('#containerdiv').fadeIn('slow');
        });
    })
});
```